# How to sort an array by passing value from first row to next row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Based on figure below it shows that start date and end date. The flow is like this :

1. User click generate button to calculate end date
2. After user click the generate button then i want the end date from the finish textbox in first row to be display in start textbox second row.
3. And after the value is passed to start then user click again generate button at the second row and it will calculate and it will be done same to next.

The view:

[image: The view]

Below is the code : 
JAVASCRIPT

```
function getDate(id) {
    id = id.match(/\d+/);

    var sd = document.getElementById('start_date'+ id).value;
    //var fd = document.getelementById('firstdate'+ id).value;
     //var ed = document.getElementById('end_date'+ id).value;
    var d = document.getElementById('duration' + id).value;        
    var m = document.getElementById('marking' + id).value;

    var date = new Date(sd);
    var newdate = new Date(date);
    var durations = parseInt(d);
    var markings = parseInt(m);


    if ( markings == 0 || markings == 1 )
    {
        newdate.setDate(newdate.getDate());

    }
    else if ( markings == 2 )
    {
         newdate.setDate((newdate.getDate() + durations)-1);
    }
    else if ( markings == 3 )
    {
         newdate.setDate(newdate.getDate() + durations);
    }


    //newdate.setDate((newdate.getDate() + durations)-1);

    var dd = newdate.getDate();
    var mm = newdate.getMonth()+1;
    var y = newdate.getFullYear();

    var someFormattedDate = y + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
    document.getElementById('end_date' + id).value = someFormattedDate;
```

HTML

```
<td style="font-family:century-gothic">

        <font color="black">Bina Stor</font>
    </td>

    <td>
      <input type="text" id="task_mark1" class="task_mark" name="task_mark" value="T1" />
    </td>

    <td>
      <input type="text"  id="marking1" class="marking" name="marking" value="0" />
    </td>

    <td>
      <input type="text" id="destination_marking1" class="destination_marking" name="destination_marking" value="0" />
    </td>

    <td>
      <input type="text" id="days1" class="days" name="days" value="0" />
    </td>

    <td>
      <input type="text" id="duration1" class="duration" name="duration" value="1" />
    </td>

    <td>
      <input type="text" id="start_date1" class="start_date" name="start_date" value="2017-02-02" />
    </td>

    <td>
      <input type="text" id="end_date1" class="end_date" name="end_date" value="" />
    </td>

    <td align="center">

      <input type="button" id ="btn1" value="GENERATE" name="action" class ="submit-green" onclick="getDate(this.id)"/>

    </td>

    </tr>

     <tr>
     <td></td>
    <td></td>
     <td style="font-family:century-gothic" >

        <font color="black">Side Rail</font>
    </td>
     <td>
      <input type="text" id="task_mark2" class="task_mark" name="task_mark" value="T2" />
    </td>

    <td>
      <input type="text"  id="marking2" class="marking" name="marking" value="3" />
    </td>

    <td>
      <input type="text" id="destination_marking2" class="destination_marking" name="destination_marking" value="0" />
    </td>

    <td>
      <input type="text" id="days2" class="days" name="days" value="0" />
    </td>

    <td>
      <input type="text" id="duration2" class="duration" name="duration" value="1" />
    </td>

    <td>
      <input type="text" id="start_date2" class="start_date" name="start_date" value="" />
    </td>

    <td>
      <input type="text" id="end_date2" class="end_date" name="end_date" value="" />
    </td>

    <td align="center">

      <input type="button" id ="btn2" value="GENERATE" name="action" class ="submit-green" onclick="getDate(this.id)"/>

    </td>

    </tr>
```

Comment: sort what array? array by date? how the data look like? it is sort by array or sort by the table that being populate? more info will be great?

Comment: 1.Title is misleading: there is no array in your code. 2. Are you always going to have 2 rows in the table? 3. The JS code looks incomplete, closing bracket for the function is missing. Without that people won't know if there is more code in that function.